# Query Repeating Records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've been studying MySQL and SQL recently, but I'm forced to work with MS Access.  I've had great success customizing and creating queries with my SQL knowledge, but now I'm stuck.  I'm still trying to learn more about properly joining tables in queries and from my experience so far, MS Access doesn't make that any easier.

I have 5 tables I'm trying to query.  Table1 (aka "munic" for "munic.ID") is the table that contains the key which connects the name to the next 4 tables.  Tables2-4 all contain multiple unique records which are related to a single entry in Table1.  When I query each Table as only a pair with Table1, I get exactly the results I need.  However, when I try to query Tables1-4 together, I get 4x as many entries (as in, Table2 records show up anywhere between 3 and 6 more times in the resultant spreadsheet).  This is also problematic because I'm trying to find a sum for the data values in Tables2-4, and with 4x the records, my sums are 4x larger.

Note: there are not an even number of records per table that are associated with the key in Table1 (Table2 has 35 entries, Table3 has 12, etc, etc)

Sample Data:

```
Table1
    ID  municipalities  county  population  website
    1   Anson   Somerset    2452    ansonmaine.town
    2   Arrowsic    Sagadahoc   440 arrowsic.org/recycling

Table2
    ID  waste-ID    munic-ID    report-year tons    cubic-yards dest-fac-ID origin
    1   45  1   2017    594     0   Maine
    2   28  1   2017    4           Maine
```

And so, here are the queries I've been working on:
Query with 2 tables, provides exact results (woo!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Table1.municipalities, 
    Table2.[report-year], 
    Sum(Table2.tons) AS [disp-tons], 
    Sum(Table2.[cubic-yards]) AS [disp-cubic-yards], Count(Table2.ID) AS [disp-no-entries]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.[munic-ID]
GROUP BY Table1.municipalities, Table2.[report-year];
```

Query with all tables (provides oh so many duplicates, it's painful):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Table1.municipalities, 
    [Table2.tons] AS Table2_tons, 
    Table2.[cubic-yards] AS [Table2_cubic-yards], 
    Table3.tons AS Table3_tons, 
    Table3.[cubic-yards] AS [Table3_cubic-yards], 
    Table4.tons AS Table4_tons, 
    Table4.[cubic-yards] AS [Table4_cubic-yards], 
    [Table5].tons AS [Table5_tons], 
    [Table5].[cubic-yards] AS [Table5_cubic-yards]
FROM (((Table1 LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.[ID] = Table3.[munic-ID]) LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[ID] = Table2.[munic-ID]) LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table1.[ID] = Table4.[munic-ID]) LEFT JOIN [Table5] ON Table1.[ID] = [Table5].[munic-ID]
ORDER BY Table1.municipalities;
```

If there's any advice about how to make it so that when I query for Table1.municipality and join on Table1 ID I don't get repeat entries, that would be very helpful. I've tried grouping the data in my query but MS requires EVERYTHING to be grouped and not just one field.  I've also done the math and when I try to sum my values as I SELECT them, I get about 4x the total it should be.

Expected result:

```
municipalities  recycle_tons    recycle_cubic-yards disposal_tons   disposal_cubic-yards    reuse_tons  reuse_cubic-yards   ben-use_tons    ben-use_cubic-yards                             
Anson   2017    114 2   598 0   0   0   0   0
Anson   2016    66  3   946 0   0   0   0   0
Arrowsic    2017    59  0   121 0   0   0   23  0
Arrowsic    2016    0   0   121 0   0   0   23  0
Auburn      2016    0   0   21428   0   0   0   1538    0
```

Actual result:

```
municipalities  report-year recycle_tons    recycle_cubic-yards disposal_tons   disposal_cubic-yards    reuse_tons  reuse_cubic-yards   ben-use_tons    ben-use_cubic-yards
Anson   2016    1       34                  
Anson   2016    1       157                 
Anson   2016    1       755                 
Anson   2016    3       34                  
Anson   2016    3       157                 
Anson   2016    3       755                 
Anson   2016    21      34                  
Anson   2016    21      157                 
Anson   2016    21      755                 
Anson   2016    43      34                  
Anson   2016    43      157                 
Anson   2016    43      755                 
Anson   2016    46      34                  
Anson   2016    46      157                 
Anson   2016    46      755                 
Anson   2017    1       4                   
Anson   2017    1       594                 
Anson   2017    3       4                   
Anson   2017    3       594                 
Anson   2017    21      4                   
Anson   2017    21      594                 
Anson   2017    43      4                   
Anson   2017    43      594                 
Anson   2017    46      4                   
Anson   2017    46      594                 
Arrowsic    2016    0       121             8
```

Hoping someone can help!  I'm eager to learn the right way to build queries this complex, since I frequently have to compile a huge amount of data from several illogically-designed MS Access databases (I inherited them from a predecessor).

UPDATE:
Below are examples of my 5 tables that I'm trying to combine records for (not as rows, but each table should be added as new columns -- but there are an uneven number of records for each table)

```
TABLE1:
    ID  municipalities  county  population  website
    1   Anson   Somerset    2452    ansonmaine.town
    2   Arrowsic    Sagadahoc   440 arrowsic.org/recycling
    3   Auburn  Androscoggin    23000   auburnmaine.gov

TABLE2:
    ID  waste-ID    munic-ID    report-year tons    cubic-yards dest-fac-ID origin
    10  1   2   2017    59          Maine
    11  20  2   2017    0           Maine
    12  21  2   2017    0           Maine

TABLE3:
    ID  waste-ID    munic-ID    report-year tons    cubic-yards dest-fac-ID origin
    1   45  1   2017    594     0   Maine
    2   28  1   2017    4           Maine
    3   45  2   2017    121         Maine

TABLE4:
    ID  waste-ID    munic-ID    report-year tons    cubic-yards dest-fac-ID origin
    1   39  9   2017    280         Maine
    2   39  12  2017    74          Maine
    3   39  18  2017    3           Maine

TABLE5:
    ID  waste-ID    munic-ID    report-year tons    cubic-yards dest-fac-ID origin
    1   29  7   2017    10  0       Maine
    4   7   12  2017    25          Maine
    5   35  15  2017    208         Maine
```

Comment: This suggests that you misunderstand how your data is set up. For instance.. you have `id` of `1` in `table1` above and you join that `id` to two records in `table2` on the `waste-id` (there are only `waste-id` values of `1` in that table. So you get two records back, but those two records are both for `table1.id` of 1. `table1.id` value of `2` doesn't make it into the results since there is no `waste-id` of `2`.

Comment: So.. because this is a problem in your data (or your understanding of it) there isn't much help we can give. If you share some sample data from each of these 5 tables so that we can understand what your SQL is doing as well as your desired results, we can, perhaps, get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, JNevill -- it looks like the formatting for the sample data has caused some confusion.  waste-id and munic-id are two seperate foreign keys that are used to reference different tables.  The key I'm using in this query is munic.id (third column of numbers in sample Table2 and first column in Table1) not waste.id (second column in Table2).  (I've also only listed 2 rows of data for each table to save some space since the tables contain a lot of data from my workplace)

Comment: One of the cornerstones of the relational model (see Ted Codd's seminal 1970 paper) is the domain name of relations (i.e., table names) which encapsulates the purpose of each table and relationships between tables. Please: 1) provide the names of your tables (*Municipalities*, *Waste*) and 2) goal of your query (i.e., sum tonnage of waste across municipalities).

Comment: You don't even show sample data for Table3 and Table4. If you include multiple tables that have multiple dependent records to the same master, you will definitely get 'duplication'. Either do multiple queries that aggregate data of the 4 tables then join those queries to Table1 or build report with subreports.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have 2 records in Table2 that have a `[munic-id]` of 1 and 3 such records in Table3, then joining all 3 tables will give you a result of 2x3=6 records with `[munic-id]` 1.

Since you seem to plan to sum the `tons` and `[cubic-yards]` for all tables Table2-5, grouped by `[munic-id]` and `[report-year]`, I suggest to do so in 4 separate queries (Query2-5) and then join the queries instead of the tables. Since the population in Table1 can change over time, I suggest to also have a table (`munic-pop`) that holds the population of a `[munic-id]` for each `[report-year]`, this will help joining the years.

The joined query could look like this (which needs no grouping anymore):

[image: munic-query]

Comment: I tried the Union option and it's a great option to have!  But it doesn't seem to be the right option for my current problem.

In the "munic" table, each "municipailty" provides data for all the next 4 tables, but the "tons" and "cubic-yards" refer to different types of material.  So when I union those queries, all of my data is appended on as rows, when they need to be combined as separate columns with each record aligning with the key that each municipality has been given.

Comment: I don't know who was talking about UNION queries, but i know that it wasn't me. With my query, you would have municipality and year together with 4 sets of 2 columns (tons and cubic-yards for all 4 materials).

Comment: I apologize! I misunderstood you when you mentioned joining queries.  I'll try joining the queries next (instead of union)!